# Как можно добавить события в коллекцию

Tags: c#, события, делегаты

День добрый!
Подскажите как мне решить задачку:

есть класс коллекции

```
public class SortBoard 
    {
        public double A { get; set; }
        public double B { get; set; }
        public double C { get; set; }


}
```

Есть объявленная коллекция:

```
public ObservableCollection<SortBoard> collection;
```

И есть основной класс программы где выполняются вычисления

```
class Program
    {
        public ObservableCollection<SortBoard> collection;
        public double k;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           collection = new ObservableCollection<SortBoard>();
            collection.Add(new SortBoard() {A=10,B=20,C=30});
            collection.Add(new SortBoard() {A=12,B=18,C=33});

           for (int i =0; i<500;i++)
           {
                if (i % 2 )
                 {
                    k=i*0.35;
                 } 
            }


       }
   }
```

Как можно реализовать событие, при котором когда "k" изменяется, чтоб обновлялись данные в коллекции по следующей логике:

A=С*2*k
B=C*3*k

Не могу понять как делегаты и события сюда прикрутить

Answer (score 1):

А зачем тебе событие?

Почему бы К не внести во внутрь какого-нибудь класса, который отвечает за хранение коллекции ? (Например, сделать наследование от `ObservableCollection`

со внесением твоей константы в расширенный класс.)

Вносишь К в виде свойства, на сеттер вешаешь триггер, который будет вызывать обновление коллекции.

По просьбам выкладываю свою реализации:

```
   namespace TestConsoleProg
{
    class Program
    {
        public class SortBoard
        {
            public double A { get; set; }
            public double B { get; set; }
            public double C { get; set; }


        }
        public class ObservableCollectionEx<SortBoard> : ObservableCollection<SortBoard>
        {
            double _k;
            public double k
            {
                get { return _k; }
                set
                {
                    _k = value;
                    foreach (dynamic t in Items)//Наверное как-то можно обойтись без динамического типа...
                                                //Если кто подскажет, скорректирую
                    {
                        t.A = t.C*2*_k;
                        t.B = t.C*3*_k;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObservableCollectionEx<SortBoard> collection;
            collection = new ObservableCollectionEx<SortBoard>();
            collection.Add(new SortBoard() { A = 10, B = 20, C = 30 });
            collection.Add(new SortBoard() { A = 12, B = 18, C = 33 });
            foreach (var val in collection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val.A);
            }
            collection.k = 3;
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Правда, я не уверен в одном моменте, который пометил комментарием, так как я не практиковал такое ранее. Если кто-нибудь подскажет, как уйти от динамика, то скорректирую ответ.

Comment: Можете показать как это реализоватт

Comment: @Spvik, выложил реализацию, но есть 1 момент, на счет которого я не уверен...

Comment: Про события, данные приходят с удаленного сервера, при изменения данного коэффициента, который используется не только в коллекции, должны пересчитываться данные в самой коллекции и меня в таблице, и соответственного   моментально отражать изменения пересчета